# I'm stuck in a Javascript variable incrementing tutorial

Tags: javascript

This is what it says:

> You can use an incrementer to make a number increase by one or a
>   decrementer to make it decrease by one. To increase the number, you
>   can use ++ after a variable.
>
> Let's make the variable i, in the editor, equal to 2 by incrementing
>   it twice. This should involve two separate lines with i++; on them.
>   Try it out now.
>
> Here you can have two separate lines of iteration. Each should contain
>   just i++.

I have to modify this code:

```
var i = 0;
print( "i is equal to " + i );
```

I'm not sure if I'm too dumb, but I don't know how to complete this tutorial.

Comment: That sounds like a bad tutorial; it isn't called an "incrementer".

Comment: @SLaks♦ How is it called then?

Comment: It's called the post-increment operator.

Comment: @SLaks When I saw "use an incrementer" I thought it was going to be a closure tutorial.

Comment: Do we really need a special operator for adding one to things? `i += 1;` please. Thank you very much.

Comment: JS vars are passed by value - it's not possible to write a closure that _changes_ a passed-in value.  All you could do is have one the _returns_ `n + 1` without changing `n`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes, of course we do.  Didn't you ever write any assembly code?

Comment: @Alnitak I did for a semester in college, but that was microcode. My point is that we don't need such an operator *in JavaScript* - we have a better alternative which is `i += 1`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas sometimes post-increment can be useful and you can't do that with a plain `i += 1`.  In any event, _every_ language that has a C origin has it, and IMHO it would have been a mistake to remove it from the language.

Comment: @Alnitak Citing that every language with C origin has it is an [appeal to tradition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_tradition) and therefore not a valid argument. Concerning post-increment, it's a question whether its usefulness outweighs the fact that it enables off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is trivially:

```
var i = 0;
i++;
i++;
print( "i is equal to " + i );
```

---

Advanced details follow:

For what it's worth, my preference would be to use the pre-incrementing `++i` operator rather than post-incrementing `i++`.

The reason for this is that strictly speaking the latter evaluates to the *original* value of `i` as it was before it was incremented, i.e as if it was a function that does this:

```
var tmp = i;
++i;
return tmp;
```

This doesn't *really* matter in Javascript, but if you progress to more advanced languages such as C++ it matters, because taking that additional copy of the object can be expensive.

Comment: @Vitimtk sure, but read the requirements from the tutorial "Here you can have two separate lines of iteration. Each should contain just i++."

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0; // it's "0"
i++; // it's "1"
i++; // it's "2"
print("i is equal to " + i) // outputs "i is equal to 2"
print("i is equal to " + ++i) // outputs "i is equal to 3"
print("i is equal to " + i++) // ouputs "i is equal to 3", but sets i to be "4"
```

Comment: You have an extra quote in your print things.